# OneNote - Copy and paste image to the table

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-onenote

When I want to have two images next to each other in OneNote, I have to put them into the table, right? So I copy some image from Chrome and paste it into the first column. Great, it's all working so far. But when I copy some other image that is already pasted in OneNote and I try to paste it into the table, it never show up.

Where is the problem? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to do what you're requiring with ON 2013.

Create table: type a character, say A (or whatever), and press tab a few times, a table is now auto created.

In cell 1 I delete the single character I created to start the table off and paste image 1, I then give focus to cell 2 and paste in image 2.

Works just fine.

Am I missing something?